# how to enable and disable a textbox in jQuery in ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Textbox where I need to disable or enable that on some Conditions.

```
var stat = "any interger"
    if (statId != 1) {
     $('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
     } 
    else {
    $('#<%=txtBQty.ClientID %>').attr("enabled", "enabled");
     }
```

This one will work but after disable if the condition returns false also means It won't enable the textbox.

Comment: What is your question? Please explain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`enabled` is not a valid attribute for `textbox`es. So the following will have no effect:

```
$('#<%=txtBQty.ClientID %>').attr("enabled", "enabled");
```

Instead use

```
$('#<%=txtBQty.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 8):

To disable

```
$('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

to enable

```
$('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable use :

```
$('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

to enable just clear the value

```
$('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do if it is in latest version of jQuery

```
var stat = "any interger";
if (statId != 1) {
     $('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').prop("disabled", true);
} 
else {
    $('#<%=txtBQty.ClientID %>').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

If you have to use `.attr()`, you can disable with `$(selector).attr('disabled','disabled')` and enable with `$(selector).removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: Got this error-"Object doesn't support this property or method"